# JavaScript Selector: find nodes which contains descendants with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Is it possible to use Javascript selector to find nodes which contains descendants with specific attribute

For example, I want to remove all not-on-sales products from current page:

```
var notPriceSales = document.querySelectorAll
    ("body div.contentArea>div.right ul>li span:not(.priceSale)")
```

This will find the price lable of not-on-sales products, but I want to find the li which has descendant: span:not(.priceSale)

so then I can remove all not-on-sales products:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( notpriceSales, function( node ) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
});
```

How can I use selector to select nodes whose descendant nodes have some special property?

Thanks

Comment: You have the question tagged with `jquery` . . . are you okay with jQuery solutions as well?

Comment: Sure, either jquery or pure js would work for me. thanks, @talemyn

Comment: Please show your HTML, or a simple concise HTML that allows you to reproduce your requirements, and show which element(s) should be matched and which should not. That way we can provide a practical answer, rather than a theoretical explanation of a possible answer; which will be more useful to you and those that come later in search of an answer. Please take the time to read the "[ask]" and "[mcve]" guidelines, they may help explain why providing code is both useful and - in many cases, if not all - expected and required.

Answer (score 2):

While certainly doable in vanilla JS, this is actually extremely straightforward in jQuery.

First off, since I can't see your HTML structure and I can only make an educated guess from the selector in your question, I'm just going to assume that there is some parent element that is common to all of these `li` tags.  To make sure that your only selecting these products spans (i.e., and not just any span on the page that doesn't have the ".priceSale" class), you can use that as the base context for your jQuery selector. I'll let you figure out what you want that to be, and will just reference it as `$parentContainer` in my code below.

Once you have that base context, it's really just a two part process to get the `li` elements that you want:

```
$parentContainer.find("span").not(".priceSale").closest("li");
```

The first part will gather all of the "non-sale" spans in the container and then the second part will collect the closest, ancestor `li` element for each span in the initial group, and put **them** into a group.

At that point, just take the resulting group of `li` elements and `.remove()` them, `display: none;` them . . . whatever you want to do to suppress them from showing.